# How is the effect called when you slap a drum stick on the metal edge of the snare?

Tags: sample, drums, technique

I am actually looking for a sample that contains this effect, like in [this song by the Red Hot Chili Peppers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GLvohMXgcBo) at 0:55

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's known as a side-stick or cross-stick

Google found this http://freewavesamples.com/side-stick

or this set looks pretty comprehensive - http://www.freesound.org/people/quartertone/packs/8839/

I didn't test either of the above, I've got more drum samples here than I really know what to do with ;)

Comment: Thank you, i was first looking for 'Rim Click' samples but that didn't give me the right samples. I got more rim shots like the second link you posted

Answer (score 2):

My drummer always called it a rimshot.

Comment: There's some confusion/disagreement over 'rimshot' as a term. I'd consider a rimshot to be like a normal stroke, but with the stick angled precisely to hit both the skin & rim simultaneously. The effect is pretty dramatic, & loud. Compared to cross- or side-stick, which has the stick resting on the skin & then the sound made by striking the rim.